# Always getting same prediction with TensorflowJS

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js

I have problem that I always get same prediction with TensorflowJS.

This is my code:

HTML: `<img id="img" src="normal_15.jpeg" style="width:300px;height:300px"></img>`

JS:

```
async function run(){
        const MODEL_URL = 'http://localhost/pneumonia_detection/model.json';
        const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(MODEL_URL);
        console.log(model.summary());
        const image = document.getElementById('img');
        var img = tf.browser.fromPixels(image, 3).resizeNearestNeighbor([180,180]).toFloat();
        const offset = tf.scalar(255.0);
        var normalized  = img.div(offset);
        console.log(img[100,100,2]);
        const axis = 0;
        normalized = img.expandDims(axis);
        console.log(normalized.shape);
        prediction = model.predict(normalized);
        console.log(prediction.dataSync());
        var pIndex = tf.argMax(prediction, 1).dataSync();
        var classNames = ["Normal", "Pneumonia"];
        alert(classNames[pIndex]);
    }
```

If it matters, in Python before inputting image into model so model make prediction, I divide image by 255.0.

I tried printing value of img and I get undefined, so it seems that I don't properly get pixels from photo. What to do to get pixels successfully?

Am I doing right processing in JS?

Answer (score 2):

I solved problem.

I don't know how I didn't notice that I wrote `normalized = img.expandDims(axis);`.

I had to write `normalized.expandDims(axis);`